Half of Surname added to First name while booking internationational flight ticket
Hi I just booked Air India tickets from Bangalore to Phuket, there was a small confusion with regards to First Name Middle Name and Last name while booking.
For Eg
As per Indian Passport Given Name- John, Surname-Allen Doe
But while booking on MakeMyTrip Via amazon it asked for "First Name and Middle Name" = John Allen , "Last Name"= Doe. Can some let me know if it's fine or should I cancel and book tickets?On the ticket though the name is correct as 'John Allen Doe' thanks

Not writing as answer as its not definite. The minor issues like this are common and check-in agent can fix that for you. Arrive early enough.

You can further clarification by talking to the airline's customer service that can even generate correct ticket for you in some cases.

Thank you all, the airline changed the names and gave us a new ticket.
